# Calculating power dissipation of a resistor

Tags: voltage, power, circuit-analysis, current, resistors

[image]

In the above circuit given where all resistances are of different values:

1. The power dissipation in red resistor is 576 W when Vs is acting alone.
2. Power dissipation in red resistor is 1 W when current source is acting alone.

Find total power dissipation in resistor.

Initially I thought that it should simply be 577 W, but there is saying that some homogeneity principle cant be used for non-linear terms like power which is V^2/R.
This question has to be solved using homogeneity principle how to approach it then?

P.S. I literally saw examples of using Total Power = Power due to source 1 + Power due to source 2 + Power due to source 3...
in AC circuits, why not applicable in DC.

Comment: _"... it should simply be 577 watts ..."_ - What is the direction of current through Rred due to Vs? What is the direction of the current through Rred due to Is?

Comment: Not mentioned in question because its obvious they are in opposite direction.

Comment: go backwards from power to current/voltage, then use the superposition principle, then work out the power again

Comment: @Adyy If the induced currents are in opposite direction, they'd subtract, and the combined power dissipation should be less than 576 Watt, not more ;)